# Rails Routes Path Trailing Slashes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Could someone please tell me why this

```
<%= destroy_password_url @user.password_reset_token %>
```

generates

```
http://localhost:3000/api/destroy_password.4G5EoRVYMUAtiIKqOerKsw
```

routes.rb

```
get 'api/destroy_password' => 'services#destroy_password', :as => 'destroy_password'
```

I'm just following http://railscasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password?view=asciicast I don't even know why it's adding a DOT. Could someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your route file, you're not saying that you accept a parameter. You should probably rewrite it like this:

```
get 'api/destroy_password/:id' => 'services#destroy_password', :as => 'destroy_password'
```